# jQuery clone and trigger create

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm trying to create a jQuery function to clone and append a text-field and select-box into the bottom of a div, like this:

```
$(".inline-form .copyIng:first-child").clone().appendTo(".inline-form");
$(".copyIng").trigger("create");
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/rxwL6/

But the 2 elements get's cloned twice and looks wired, any ideas why this happens?

Greeting :)

## I'm sorry for answering my own question

, but the solution looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newIng").click(function(){
  $(".inline-form .copyIng:first-child").clone().appendTo(".inline-form");
  });

  $("#newOve").click(function(){
    $('<div class="ove"><input type="text" name="c[]" class="field" placeholder="Overskrift"></div>').appendTo(".inline-form");
    $(".field").textinput();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it what you want http://jsfiddle.net/rxwL6/2/ ?

Comment: Exactly, but later on when I add a text field, I need to trigger create.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use `refrash` event. The `create` event is suited for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets. The `refresh` method should be used on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxwL6/5/

Comment: Okay, great, but why can't i select anything from the dropdown created?